# Hide table row by dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 dropdown menu (Username & Gender) and I have table with 3 columns (username, name, and gender).
I want to filter the table based on dropdown value. What must I do ?

Here's the code :

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker">
    <option value="">Username</option>
    <option value="">user1</option>
    <option value="">user2</option>
    <option value="">user3</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control selectpicker">
    <option value="">Gender</option>
    <option value="">M</option>
    <option value="">F</option>

</select>
</div>

<table class="dynamicTable tableTools table table-striped table-primary">
    <!-- Table heading -->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>user1</td>
            <td>Jane</td>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user2</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>M</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user3</td>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td>M</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <!-- // Table body END -->
</table>
<!-- // Table END -->
```

Comment: First thing to do before asking here would be trying by yourself...

Comment: do u have any tutorial for this sir ? the simple one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I create this sollution.

**html**

```
<select id="username" class="form-control selectpicker">
    <option value="">Username</option>
    <option value="">user1</option>
    <option value="">user2</option>
    <option value="">user3</option>
</select>

<select id="gender" class="form-control selectpicker">
    <option value="">Gender</option>
    <option value="">M</option>
    <option value="">F</option>

</select>

<table class="dynamicTable tableTools table table-striped table-primary">
    <!-- Table heading -->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>user1</td>
            <td>Jane</td>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user2</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>M</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user3</td>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td>M</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <!-- // Table body END -->
</table>
```

**js**

```
$("#username").on("change",
               function(){
                   var a = $(this).find("option:selected").html();

                   $("table tr td:first-child").each(
                       function(){
                           if($(this).html() != a){
                               $(this).parent().hide();
                           }
                           else{
                               $(this).parent().show();
                           }
                       });
               });

$("#gender").on("change",
               function(){
                   var a = $(this).find("option:selected").html();

                   $("table tr td").each(
                       function(){
                           if($(this).html() != a){
                               $(this).parent().hide();
                           }
                           else{
                               $(this).parent().show();
                           }
                       });
               });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V8ke2/12/)

Comment: thank sir, i already try exactly same like this post but it doesn't work, i dont know why but maybe i missing something ?? That example on the link ('fiddle') is what i need. I just don't know whats wrong with my computer, sorry im newbie

Comment: It has nothing to do with your computer. You must probably missing something. Did you include jquery library?

Comment: must i include jquery library ? i just need that script sir, i make it in 1 file (html and js), i insert ur js code to <script></script>, is it wrong ?

Comment: yes there is one error 'uncaught referenceError : $is not defined'. How should i fix this sir ?

Comment: You have to add jquery library into header of your code. There are two ways. 1) Direct link from google `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` or download from `http://jquery.com/download/` and add to your project. Hope it helps :)

Comment: i already tried that 2 ways but still dont work :( dont know what to do

Comment: btw whats this mean sir 'td:first-child' ?

Comment: It selects the first `<td>`in a `<tr>`

Answer (score 2):

I made a simple script with jQuery (you have to include the jquery library).

**HTML:**

```
<select name="username" class="form-control selectpicker">
    <option value="">Username</option>
    <option value="">user1</option>
    <option value="">user2</option>
    <option value="">user3</option>
</select>

<select name="gender" class="form-control selectpicker">
    <option value="">Gender</option>
    <option value="">M</option>
    <option value="">F</option>

</select>
</div>

<table id="tbl" class="dynamicTable tableTools table table-striped table-primary">
    <!-- Table heading -->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>user1</td>
            <td>Jane</td>
            <td>F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user2</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>M</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user3</td>
            <td>Jack</td>
            <td>M</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <!-- // Table body END -->
</table>
<!-- // Table END -->
```

**Javascript (jQuery):**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function calculate() {
        $('#tbl tbody tr').show();
        var sel_username = $('select[name="username"] option:selected').text();
        var sel_gender = $('select[name="gender"] option:selected').text();

        if(sel_username == 'Username' && sel_gender == 'Gender') {
            return;
        }

        $('#tbl tbody tr').each(function() {
            var col_username = $(this).find('td').first();
            var col_gender = $(this).find('td').last();

            if(col_username.text() !== sel_username && sel_username !== 'Username') {
                $(this).hide();
            }

            if(col_gender.text() !== sel_gender && sel_gender !== 'Gender') {
                if($(this).is(':visible')) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    $('select[name="username"]').change(function() {
        calculate();
    });

    $('select[name="gender"]').change(function() {
        calculate();
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M7L6T/2/)**

Comment: thanks sir this is what i need but i don't know it doesnt work in my computer, maybe i missing something ??

Comment: Did you include the jquery library? You can find it here: [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) And you noticed the id at the table and the names at the select-elements?

Comment: You have to add `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>` before `</body>` in your script. Or in `<head>`.

Comment: must i inclue jquery library ?? i try exactly like ur code sir